# Can I iterate list of properties without losing type checking?

Tags: typescript

Consider this simple code:

```
applySelectedOrganization(apiData) {
  this.formFields.producer.fullName = apiData.fullName;
  this.formFields.producer.kpp = apiData.kpp;
  this.formFields.producer.inn = apiData.inn;
  this.formFields.producer.ogrn = apiData.ogrn;
  this.formFields.producer.shortName = apiData.shortName;
  //# missing fields? address x2, site; phone?
}
```

If `this.formFields` implements an interface, this code is type-checked and if I add

```
  this.formFields.producer.unexisting = apiData.some;
```

I'll be warned.

However, the code above is too verbose (and in some cases there can be more complicated stuff than just copying - like validating etc - for each prop), I'd rewrite it as

```
applySelectedOrganization(apiData) {
  for(let prop of ['fullName', 'kpp', 'inn', 'ogrn', 'shortName'])
    this.formFields.producer[prop] = apiData[prop];
  //# missing fields? address x2, site; phone?
}
```

but in that case I lose the type checking.

Can I somehow rewrite the loop (or iterate the prop names in any other form) so that compile-time type checking is not lost?

Answer (score 1):

You could first iterate through the `apiData` and then check each property to ensure that it exists on the `Producer` interface.

```
export interface Producer {
    fullName: string;
    kpp: string;
    inn: string;
    ogrn: string;
    shortName: string;
    [propName: string]: any;
}

export interface ApiData {
    [propName: string]: any;
}

export interface Form {
    producer: Producer;
}


function applySelectedOrganization(form: Form, apiData: ApiData) {
  for (let prop in apiData) {
      if (prop in formFields.producer) {
          form.producer[prop] = apiData[prop];
      } else {
          console.log(`Warning: invalid property ${prop}.`)
      }
  }
}

const data = {
    "fullName": "Mel Brooks",
    "inn": "123",
    "ogrn": "Brooksfilms",
    "shortName": "Mel",
    "random_prop": "should show warning"
};

let formFields: Form = {
    producer: {fullName: '', kpp: '', inn: '', ogrn: '', shortName: ''}
};

applySelectedOrganization(formFields, data);
console.log(JSON.stringify(formFields, null, 2));
```

## Output

```
Warning: invalid property random_prop.

{
  "producer": {
    "fullName": "Mel Brooks",
    "kpp": "",
    "inn": "123",
    "ogrn": "Brooksfilms",
    "shortName": "Mel"
  }
}
```

Comment: yeah, this trick may be helpful, but it's for run-time while I'm looking for compile-time warnings